# At the apple store, will they change the color of the front display from white to black?

Tags: iphone

I have a new iphone 7 plus, in rose gold, which I realized had a white front display only when I got home. Will apple change the front display to black if I bring it in?

Answer (score 2):

iPhone in Rose Gold only comes with a white front panel. There is no way to change it to a black front panel, at the Apple store or otherwise.

The only colors that come with a black front panel are Black and Jet Black.